# CF partitions not showing up in Workbench

Tags: amiga, hard-disk, file-system

4GB Compact Flash
KS 3.1 40.68
WB3.1
Latest WinUAE

I just created a Compact Flash (compatible Transcend) partitions under Workbench on latest WinUAE using [this](https://johan.driessen.se/posts/Setting-up-a-Compact-Flash-card-with-Classic-Workbench-and-WHDLoad-for-Amiga-600-1200/) guide. Despite following the steps my CF doesn't show up in WB, therefore I cannot format partition.

I can format it to Windows and use it alright. But each time I clean it in diskpart and set partitions again under WinUAE it just doesn't show. I tried to mount it on IDE auto, UAEHF.DEVICE, SCSI. Still doesn't show up.

When I go to HDTools, however, it shows as one partition used not 2 or 3 I created. I don't have other card handy now, anyway to fix it before it arrives?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try partitioning and formatting it on the Amiga instead, and then loading it into WinUAE?

That would create the correct Amiga RDB instead a DOS MBR bootblock.

Answer (score 0):

CF has to be removed from Windows after partitioning and WinUAE completely closed and reopened once again with Admin rights.

Comment: well if you don't open winuae in admin mode it's impossible to use harddisks or CF cards. You can't even select them in the UI

Comment: Ofcourse, otherwise I wouldn't be able to perform previous steps

Comment: you don't need admin rights anymore to read CF cards (to my surprise)